# 'str' object is not callable when using find element by class | Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

When I'm wring following code, unable to click on button. It shows error "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Code

```
   shopping_btn = self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME("cta cta-hover-animate cta-fill-black-outline-black"))
   shopping_btn.click()
```

Error:

> File "E:\Python\setests\smoketest.py", line 33, in
> test_shopping_cart_empty_message
> shopping_btn = self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME("cta cta-hover-animate cta-fill-black-outline-black")) TypeError: 'str'
> object is not callable

Comment: Okay, so what is your *question* about this? And what happened when you tried to diagnose the problem? For example, did you *read* the error message? Did you *understand* the error message? Did you try to figure out, for example, which part of the line of code is causing the problem? Did you try to verify, for example, that `self.driver` is what you expect it to be? Or any of the other sub-expressions on that line of code? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

you need to use find_element like this:

```
shopping_btn = self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "cta cta-hover-animate cta-fill-black-outline-black")
shopping_btn.click()
```

the exception appeared, due to trying to call

```
By.CLASS_NAME('<your_selector>')
```

what is equal

```
"any_string"('<you_selector>')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's using multiple class names use css selector.

```
shopping_btn = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".cta.cta-hover-animate.cta-fill-black-outline-black")
shopping_btn.click()
```